PHP scandir() gives "Permission Denied" even though apache has permissions to directory
When I use PHP's scandir() as follows:
$basedir = "/var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg";
$available_runs = scandir($basedir);
I get

Warning: scandir(/var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /var/www/html/mike/ddashboard.php on line 15" error.

However, when I navigate to this directory,
ls -ltr
It returns
drwxrwsrwx. 7 apache          domain users    65  June 27 22:44 DroughtAgg
Which indicates to me that PHP should in fact have access to this directory.  I also ran a getfacl on both DroughtAgg and the parent folder, which scandir() can access successfully, and found no differences of note.

Create new directory and check if you access that directory or not. Then compare the permissions of both directories

Have apache the right to access the parent directories?

if you're running PHP using PHP-FPM there's always the chance your PHP user is different than you apache user, this should be specified in your FPM pool config. Also the default apache user is called www-data on some systems so make sure you've got the right user

Apart from the above (if all above suggestions fail), then likely it is due to directory protection. in that case try using chattr -i /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg ,  chattr -i /var/www/html/mike and see whether it fixes your permission problem

So, I confirmed that the correct user is apache, to rule that out.  What's so weird is that Apache can indeed access the parent directories, all the way through /var/www/html/mike.  I have confirmed that the permissions are identical on /var/www/html/mike and /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg.

So, I tried running a chattr -i on my directories, to no avail.  Running a lsattr /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg returned no particular attributes, to begin with, though.

Look for SELinux, AppArmor and similar tools. File system permissions can be more complicated than just file attributes.

You nailed it.  Don't know why I didn't think about SELinux.  Original directory was user_home_t, while Apache needed it to have httpd_sys_content for PHP to be able to access it.  Updated the contexts and the problem is resolved.  Thanks!!!

There are couple of things to need to check i.e.

Your PHP script should run under that user which has permissions to access the directory. Try the following script for this:

<?php
echo 'Current PHP user: ' . get_current_user();
?>


Secondly, check the user returned from the above script has necessary permissions for this directory /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg

Check the Apache Error Log also.

Check PHP has permissions to read Directories. You need to check your php.ini for that.



So, get_current_user() returns my own user account (mike).  This user has permission to read the whole directory structure.

Weirder still, when I create a completely new collection of directories, they have identical permissions to the ones I can't read, but PHP can read the new ones.
Originally, the DroughtAgg/ directory was in my home directory.  Rather than creating it in /var/www/html/mike, I moved it there after creating it and its subdirectories.  This must have been related to the problem somehow.

It's possible that some of the extended attributes or SELinux contexts didn't update correctly.
sudo chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg
Also, reapply the permissions:
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/mike/DroughtAgg
Also, Ensure ACL's are set correctly
